# Customizing IdentityUser from dotnet new webapp --auth Individual -o

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm learning about C# and dotnet core, I am currently working on the template

```
    dotnet new webapp --auth Individual -o WebApp1
```

However, it does a lot of things for me behind the scenes that I don't understand.

I'm rummaging through the code to find how the login view is created and handled, but have had no such luck.
Currently, I am attempting to add a column to the database given in this template, shown I think here:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dotnet core team decided to abstract their default UI for authentication in a Razor Library, look for a Dependency -> SDK ->  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI

Look at the code for this package [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Identity/UI/src)

This should give you an idea of what is actually going on int the background.

As for extending the User model

```
public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
{
     //custom properties
}
```

Then you want to configure Identity middle ware to recognise this as the main model for your users.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<CustomUser>();
```

Don't forget to update your database inheritance so the correct table is created.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser> 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, for anyone as green as me who finds this, you'll need to add a migration to your database using `dotnet ef migrations add TestingUser` and then update using `dotnet ef database update` at which point your database will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

`IdentityUser` is the base "user" class for Identity, so it's filling that in so no additional effort is required on your part. That's fine if you don't want to customize the user, but since you obviously do, simply just create your own class that derives from `IdentityUser`:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Then, use your custom user class as the type param in place of `IdentityUser`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyUser>()
```